# Filter processes by module's FileName

Tags: powershell

If I need to filter processes by a module's FileName, the following code does the job:

```
Get-Process | where { $_.Modules.FileName -eq "xxx\yyy.dll”) }
```

But if I need to filter modules by FileName starting with a string, the following code doesn't seem to work:

```
Get-Process | where { $_.Modules.FileName.StartsWith("xxx\yyy.dll”)) }
```

As result, I see all the processes in the output. I'm very confused why filtering doesn't seem to work in case of StartsWith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member `modules` might be a collection. Thus it needs to be iterated too. Like so,

```
(get-process) | % {
    if($_.modules -ne $null) { # No modules, no action
        $_.modules | ? { $_.filename.tolower().startswith("c:\program") }
    }
}
```

As for the question, there are actually two iterations. Let's use explicit variables instead of pipelining and printing the acutal module files. Passing multiple `$_`s around is not easy to read syntax anyway. Like so,

```
foreach ($p in get-process) {
    if ($p.modules -ne $null){
        write-host $p.id $p.ProcessName
        foreach($m in $p.modules){
            if ($m.filename.tolower().startswith("c:\program") ) {
                write-host `t $m.moduleName $m.FileName # ` markdown bug
            }
        } 
        write-host
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It does sound like the right solution but do you have any idea why equality check works without an iteration?